# Generate random number/word that stays on page for a certain amount of time surviving a reload

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to generate a random word/number and that value output stays in the page even after reloading it for a certain amount of time till the user can generate another random word/number again. If possible the time can also be shown?

Comment: yes possible use localstorage or session storage

Comment: What time though?

Comment: based on hours? if thats what your looking for?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and code and don't put a large description in the title

Answer (score 0):

You should have done some research and the best answer would be `localStorage`. Here's a very basic setup using `Date.getTime()` and `Math.random()` too generate a random number.

```
<p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="generateKeyBtn">Generate</button> a new random key</p>
<span id="key"></span>
```

And JavaScript:

```
const
  keyBtn = document.getElementById('generateKeyBtn'),
  keySpan = document.getElementById('key');

// Retrieves the key from localStorage and shows it in the span
const showKey = () => {

  if ('localStorage' in window) {

    let key = localStorage.getItem('randomKey');

    if (key) keySpan.innerHTML = key;

  }

}

// Saves the key to localStorage
const saveKey = (k) => {

  if ('localStorage' in window) {

    localStorage.setItem('randomKey', k);

  }

}

// Generate a random key
// based on the current time and Math.random()
const generateKey = () => {

  let d = new Date(),
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * d.getTime());

  saveKey(r);
  showKey();

}


keyBtn.addEventListener('click', generateKey);

// Show the initial key if it exists
showKey();
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/u3ynuc9h/)